# The set of all possible values of subseries of a convergent positive term series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Inspired by [The set of all limits of sub-series of an absolute convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062357/the-set-of-all-limits-of-sub-series-of-an-absolute-convergent-series) is the following true?:

> Let $a_n$ be a strictly decreasing sequence and $\sum_1^\infty  a_n=\ell<\infty$ is a convergent series. Is it true to say that the set of all possible value of all subseries $\sum a_{n_i}$ of $\sum a_n$ is whole $[0,\ell]$?

Comment: If $a_n = 2\cdot(\frac{1}{3})^n$ (numbering from $n=1$) then the set in question is precisely the standard Cantor set (seen as the set of reals in $[0,1]$ having a base $3$ expression consisting only of $0$ and $2$), so, no.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen  Thank you for this example

Comment: @Gro-Tsen   so  under what condition the answer is  affirmative?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen   Is $\sum (1/2^n) $ is  some what an exception? I mean what can be said about the space of all positive sequence whith connected subseries values?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen  your interesting example of the Cantor set is a motivation to assigne a real number to every positive terms series: the  Hausdorff dimension of the set of all  subseries values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For convenience define $S_n = \sum_{j\le n} a_j$ and $T_n = \sum_{j > n} a_j$.

Suppose there is $n$ such that $a_n > T_n$.  Then for $S_{n-1} + T_n < x < S_n$,
$x$ is not the sum of a subseries.

On the other hand, if $a_n \le T_n$ for all $n$, then every $x \in [0,\ell]$ is the sum of a subseries.  This can be obtained "greedily": include $a_n$ iff the sum of $a_n$ and already-included terms $\le x$.

Comment: Thank you  very much for this perfect answer

Comment: Is there a terminology for such kind of  sequences?  may be  a reference  for  such kind of seuqnces?

Answer (score 7):

No. Consider the sequence $1 + 10^{-10} + 10^{-100}+10^{-1000}+ \cdots$. You can't possibly find a subsequence adding up to $1/2$, because the tail is so small.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Under what condition the answer is affirmative? is there a terminology for positive series with connected set of all possible sub series value?

Comment: Is $\sum (1/2^n) $ is  some what an exception? I mean what can be said about the space of all positive sequence whith connected subseries values?